# How to make visible icons like data-feather="chevron-down"?

Tags: laravel

Into my laravel 8 app with tailwindcss2/inertiajs I try to apply tailwindcss2 styles which have a lot of icons like :

```
<i data-feather="chevron-down"></i></div>
```

I do not see any icons, though I applyed all css files from source templates.

It does not look like package

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
```

which I use in my laravel apps

Which packages/fonts have I to add to my app to see these icons?
In package.json I have :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.10.0",
    "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.5.1",
    "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.6",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-loader": "^16.1.2"
},
"dependencies": {
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Font-Awesome works well on standard `<i>` HTML with classes.

Perhaps give this a try:

```
<i class="chevron-down"></i>
```

If you are looking for the feather icon JS, you may be crossing the streams here, that may be a separate package of SVG icons (unpkg.com) that needs to be loaded as a script.

E.g.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
```

Comment: I added link     <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons@4.28.0/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
 in  resources/views/app.blade.php file but it did not help.  I was redirected to this link when I tried to open your link. Have I do add some css ?

Comment: You can try this one: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>` as well, but I think the issue is that you are crossing two different icon sets.  If you have loaded font-awesome, try with the class as in the answer above.  Or try with the feather loading the script for Feather.  But, if you are going to use Feather - I think would help to review the docs and the library here: https://github.com/feathericons/feather

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you havn't initialized feather icons by:

`feather.replace()`

```js
// init feather icons
feather.replace()
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons@4.28.0/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
<!-- example icons -->
<i data-feather="eye"></i>
<i data-feather="heart"></i>
<i data-feather="feather"></i>
```

BTW. fontAwesome uses different icon class names. So you should't encounter any conflicts.